# My preventDefault not working in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

I have something like this HTML structure.

```
<input type="text" id="client-first-name" autocomplete="given-name" class="input-small error" data-bind="value: firstName, validate: 'alphaNumericPunctuation', valueUpdate:'afterkeydown', required: true, disable: loading">
```

I'm trying to do a validation so that the input only accepts text. All validation works correctly but prototype preventDefault() is not working. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#client-first-name").keyup(function(event){

    if(!/^[A-Z]+$/i.test(event.key)){
        event.preventDefault()

      }
  })
})
```

Comment: you mean `isDefaultPrevented` as that's what you're calling

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be preventDefault

Comment: Your code is fine. Use `console.log(event.isDefaultPrevented());` to verify in your console and you will see that it retruns `true`.

Comment: change .keyup to .keypress

Comment: keypress worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `input` event instead, as it won't work. And get the last character of `event.target.value`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#client-first-name").on('input', function(event){

    var newValue = event.target.value

    if(!/^[A-Z]+$/i.test(newValue[newValue.length - 1])){
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: event.preventDefault still doesnt work